# Unable to start mongod

Tags: mongodb

When I try to start Mongod, I get the following error

```
sai@saip:~/js_learning$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8671 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=saip
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lamiak 2.6.42-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:28:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_46_1
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] options: {}
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 dbexit: 
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Feb 12 15:50:54 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I get the same error if I try to run mongoid --repair

Comment: Do you try to set a `dbpath` when init mongo? `mongod --dbpath /path/to/data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a folder /data/db, and start server by giving the command

```
./mongod
```

If write permission is required, then use

```
sudo ./mongod
```

2) If you want to use custom path, then create folder at any location.
Then you can start the server by giving below command

In Linux, Lets say created folder is '/home/mongo/db'

```
./mongod --bpath /home/mongo/db
```

In Windows, Lets say created folder is 'd:\mongodb\data'

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\mongodb\data
```

Comment: At which directory should I create /data/db?

Comment: In root directory only. If you are confused with that opt the second way.

Comment: Once I set the --dbpath it is listening for connections, but when I stop mongod and run it again it gives the same old error.

Comment: Once it starts listening, open command prompt and say `./mongo` to start a mongoDB client. To avoid old errors while starting `mongod` always use `--dbpath < path >`

Comment: No. That is working. What I meant was, after that when I stop mongod and start mongod again, I am getting the`code` dbpath (/data/db/)  does not exist , terminating `code` error again. So I need to set dbpath everytime I am trying to use mongo now.

Comment: Yes, you need to set the path every time. If you don't want to set it, create `/data/db/` folder. Then you don't need to use `--dbpath` every time.

Comment: I already have the /data/db folder as var/lib/mogodb/data/db. Do I need to create it elsewhere?

Comment: Are you using Linux?, If so create `/data/db` as it is from command prompt.
From command prompt, stay in root directory and say `mkdir data` and `cd data`, then `mkdir db`. That would be enough.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I need to do sudo mongod, instead of mongod for it to work. How do I make it work with just mongod?

Comment: Yes, As i mentioned earlier, if it says write access denied, you should use `sudo ./mongod` to start the mongodb server.